# Debian Live-CD user password

Tags: debian, gnome, kde, xfce, password

I am trying to use Debian live from an USB, however I do not succeed in logging in…

**What is the standard user and password to get access?**

I have tried searching this question on the internet and used combinations of standard user credentials that I found such as live/live, root/root, root/live, and combinations without a password. None of them worked.

This problem applies to Gnome, KDE, Xfce for me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could either try using `user:live` as username:password combination or adding `live-config` to the boot options (as suggested here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=102937 ) which should log you in automatically.

Comment: Many thanks!! Actually, I had created a bootable USB drive based on EFI to boot. However, when directly copying the Debian image to USB, it boots just fine, without any user credential issues. I really appreciate your prompt response.